# Image scale and animation improvement

Tags: css, image, performance, width, scale

Can someone know how scale (width) to 100% of the screen a `img` element and keep big performances in animation ?

In my first example, i set the `width` property to `100%`. For testing purpose i made a animation loop in this fiddle to see performance chunk : http://jsfiddle.net/tXXmm/1/.
I have **35fps** when the image is hidden by the `overflow` of the parent element.

When i remove the `width` property, i have **60fps** to the same example : http://jsfiddle.net/tXXmm/2/

[image]

I need to know if there is some methodology to get the same result as the first example, with the performance of the second example.
Please consider : The image resolution is variable. Only the parent element has `height: 500px;`. Also, my design is a *fluid* design (this is why the width of my image needs to scale the full width of the screen).

Any solutions is appreciated (PHP, JS, CSS...).
Thank you!

Comment: how about getting the width of the window via javascript and then setting it to the image.

Comment: Hi @stackErr, thanks for the answer! It seems not changing the performance of the image (35fps in the fiddle). It's because the image has not the original width i guess (?)

Comment: what about setting attribute with real height/width in HTML and reset width in CSS ? At least no need for the browser to fully upload image to know it's size. http://jsfiddle.net/tXXmm/4/ (if this your answer , i'll make one of it)

Comment: Hello @GCyrillus and thank you for the comment! In your fiddle, the framerate is still at 30/35fps. Check for yourself, when you detele the "width" property in CSS, the framerate goes up to 60fps. In fact, I need to get this performance, but with the image to 100% of the width of the parent container. *EDIT* : This is the test I made with your update http://jsfiddle.net/tXXmm/5/

Comment: sounds like i miss read , sorry :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found something. I have added `transform: translateZ(0);` and now i got 60fps in Google Chrome! http://jsfiddle.net/tXXmm/7/.

It appears this property force the activation of GPU Acceleration in webkit browsers. It's seems to be a good tip to go for now. Thank you for your help!