# How set a image as a background, without background-image property?

Tags: jquery, css, performance, background

I have a image inside a block. The image take `100%` of the width of my screen. The parent block take `500px` in height, and also `100%` of the screen width. I've set `overflow: hidden` to the parent block so I can view only the first 500px of my image in height.

Now, my problem is, when I resize the window of my browser, I need to scale the image exactly as a background. I cannot use a background-image because of performance issues (reflows, etc...).

I made this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d5xDz/). How can i make the second image the same reaction of the first image? Please note, the image, in my case has random resolutions.

Thank you for your help!
It's ok if the solution needs to be in JS/jQuery.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/d5xDz/1/ ?

Comment: Hello @RoryPickering! Thanks for the answer but if you resize down your window you will see the red color and the first block has another reaction.

Comment: I don't fully understand the question, why is your orginal jsfiddle not good enough? the with background-image:cover? why must you use an img tag?

Comment: @RoryPicko92 This is because of the poor performance of `background-image` VS `img` when you use some animations. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17477064/image-scale-and-animation-improvement for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set a `min-width` and `min-height` on your `img`. This will need to be in proportion to your wrapper. So for the fiddle example, with an image size of `1024/768`, it is as [this fiddle shows](http://jsfiddle.net/d5xDz/6/):

```
min-width: 333.33px; /* the ratio of height of img to height of wrapper applied to img width */
min-height: 250px; /* the height setting of the wrapper */
```

Comment: This is working for me! Thank you! I have this another issue if you can help me two! Thanks anyway! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17438452/css-set-relative-position-to-an-image-inside-a-block